# Exception when trying to set Arguments

Tags: android, kotlin, exception

I am trying to save a bundle to arguments, but when `setArguments()` aka `arguments = bundle` is called, the following exception occurs

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added and state has been saved
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.setArguments(Fragment.java:655)
    at com.sen.osmo.ui.fragments.MYFRAGMENT.onSaveInstanceState(MYFRAGMENT.kt:775)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performSaveInstanceState(Fragment.java:2863)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.saveBasicState(FragmentStateManager.java:434)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.saveState(FragmentStateManager.java:400)
```

the code is as follows

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    bundle.putBoolean(key, value)
    arguments = bundle
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
}
```

On another possible solution to overcome this, I have tried not to set the arguments but set only the `outState` bundle, as below, but when called, the `savedInstanceState: Bundle?` on `onCreateView` and everywhere is always null.

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    outState.putBoolean(key, value)
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
}
```

Comment: I think you don't understand Activity-lifecycle very well. What do you want to accomplish, what are you saving bundle to arguments? if you are using onSaveInstanceState you should be using onRestoreInstanceState too.

Comment: I am using onRestoreInstanceState, i just didnt write that here

Comment: do you have any idea regarding the exception ?

Comment: yes you are reassigning arguments bundle and you should not do that and there is no need for that, that is why I am asking what are you trying to do?